# Change scope based on parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I change a scope on a chain dynamically based on a parameter in the URI?

For example:

http://www.example.com/object?status=approved

would lead to the `ObjectController#index`:

```
def index
  @objects = Object.approved.<other-chains>
end
```

If `status` was `pending`, the controller method would be something like:

`@objects = Object.pending.<other-chains>`

Comment: You might consider `/objects/approved` and `/objects/pending`, which is more Rails-y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't. You'd define two scopes, `pending` and `approved`, and invoke them conditionally based on the URL. You can't (or at the very least, shouldn't) change your scopes dynamically at run time, or you're going to *break* subsequent requests terribly.

If you want to avoid branching if/elses, you can just `send` the method to your model, after making sure that it is in a pre-approved list of acceptable methods:

```
class MyController

  def index
    @objects = Object.send(scope).chain.chain.chain
  end

protected

  # return "pending", "approved", or "scoped", 
  #   so that Object.send(scope) *always* works, and returns a chainable relation
  def scope
    scopes = %w(pending approved)
    scopes.include?(params[:status].to_s) ? params[:status] : "scoped"
  end

end
```

By defaulting to ["scoped"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes), you ensure that the method invoked will return a relation onto which additional methods can be chained.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
@objects = Object.send(params[:status])
```

Comment: Can that be chained with other scopes?

Comment: It can be chained as long as the params[:status] returns an ActiveRecord::Relation (i.e., it even IS a scope on your object). But this is extremely dangerous, what if I were to pass in "destroy_all" to your controller? You need to filter your status parameter first to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: As Logan says, allowing this without first filtering the params against a whitelist is *extremely* dangerous. You should *never* just slam user-supplied data into a `send`; you're willfully letting the user execute arbitrary code in your app.

Comment: Agreed. I was just directly answering the question, but you should definitely take security into account. Thanks for making those points, everyone.

Comment: Oh, totally - I take security very seriously.  Thanks all!